# How can I enable command line history on a remote Ubuntu terminal session?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, ssh, terminal

When logging into a remote Ubuntu session using ssh, my command line history, which I'd usually access on my local terminal with the cursor keys is replaced with ^]]A ^]]B characters etc.

How can I enable the command line history on this remote session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it turns out my login was set to use /bin/sh.  I changed my login shell to bash by changing /etc/passwd and my problems were solved